# How to make images, text, and description section align?

Tags: html, css, icons, vertical-alignment

I currently have this section, and they are not really aligned. I want to make each element aligned as the one next to it.

[image]

As you can see above, icons, title, and description are not aligned, as it affected by the icons.

Below is my code:

```
<div class="steps-icons">
     <div class="steps-icons-section steps-icons-first">
          <img src="{{media url=wysiwyg/landing_page/how_it_works/You_Pick_It_Icon.png}}" alt="You pick it" />
          <h6> You Pick It </h6>
          <p> Select a box option based on your craving </p>
     </div>
     <div class="steps-icons-section steps-icons-second">
          <img src="{{media url=wysiwyg/landing_page/how_it_works/We_Build_It_Icon.png}}" alt="We build it" />
          <h6> We Build It </h6>
          <p> We create your box with the names and flavors you love </p>
     </div>
     <div class="steps-icons-section steps-icons-third">
          <img src="{{media url=wysiwyg/landing_page/how_it_works/Delivered_Icon.png}}" alt="Delivered Icon" />
          <h6> Delivered </h6>
          <p> No more runs to the gas station or over paying </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* How it works */
.steps-icons {
    display: flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .steps-icons {
        flex-direction: column;
        display: block;
    }
}
.steps-icons-section {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 20px 20px 20px;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your .steps-icons-section css.

```
.steps-icons-section {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

It should align them to the bottom of the div.